# Are Kotlin Lists... "instantiable" interfaces?

Tags: inheritance, kotlin, collections, abstract-class

So I have a class that models a string of bits. This would be great to do with a plain old list of ints but to practice a bit I wanted to derive a Kotlin collection.

I want to derive a basic immutable collection. In Java `List` is an interface. In Kotlin this also seems to be the case. The documentation says it is, so logic says that it can't be instantiated. However... if that is the case then what does `listOf()` return?

Runnig a simple `listOf()` in the Kotlin REPL gives a result that indicated that `List` is instantiable.

```
listOf(1,2,3)
res: kotlin.collections.List<kotlin.Int> = [1, 2, 3]
```

My questions are:

1. Is `List` instantiable?
2. If not then what does `listOf` return and why does Kotlin say it is a `List`?
3. And what "basic" immutable collection (that is already implemented so I don't have to implement it from scratch) should I extend knowing that I want to end up with a regular immutable collection with functionalities like filter/map/index/etdc. and with a few extra methods?

Comment: Look at Java's `List.of`, or at `Collections.singletonList`. They also return `List`.

Answer (score 1):

listOf returns implementations of List interface - either EmptyList, Collections.singletonList(element) or elements.asList()

I would say that you should use listOf exactly for point number 3 :)

Answer (score 1):

To extend r2rek's answer:

> 1. Is `List` instantiable?

No.  As in Java, it's an interface.*

(It differs from Java mainly in the Kotlin compiler hides all the mutation methods.  Instead, those are available in a new sub-interface, `MutableList`.  That makes it easier to tell the compiler what's mutable and what isn't.  The JVM only sees `List`, though.)

The REPL is telling you the type of the reference, not the type of the concrete class it's pointing to.  Here's another example:

```
>>> val n: Number = 1
>>> n
res1: kotlin.Number = 1
>>> n::class
res2: kotlin.reflect.KClass<out kotlin.Number> = class kotlin.Int
```

> 2. If not then what does `listOf` return and why does Kotlin say it is a `List`?

It returns some implementation of `List`.  It doesn't tell you which one, and your code shouldn't know or care.  (If it does, you should create something more specific instead!)

The `listOf()` method will of course know the concrete type it's creating, but the method signature simply returns `List`.  This is so that it can return different implementations for different inputs.

(For example, it may return the same empty list instance for every call with no elements; and it may choose different implementations for small and large lists.  And future versions are free to tweak that for performance.  As long as your code only relies on it returning something that implements `List`, then it'll still work fine.)

> 3. And what "basic" immutable collection […] should I extend knowing that I want to end up with a regular immutable collection with functionalities like filter/map/index/etdc. and with a few extra methods?

You're probably doing fine with whatever type of `List` `listOf()` gives you.

You could write your own implementation if you needed some very unusual behaviour, but 99% of the time there's no real benefit (and lots of opportunity for making mistakes and losing out on future improvements).

Remember that in addition to the basic methods that the `List` interface contains, Kotlin also lets you use the host of extension methods in the standard library (`any()`, `associate()`, `chunked()`, `count()`…).  So you get loads of functionality ‘for free’!

---

(* To confuse the issue, Kotlin does have a function `fun <T> List(size: Int, init: (Int) -> T): List<T>`.  Calling this *looks* like calling a constructor, but it's not!)

Comment: `List` requires me to implement methods like `size`, etc. because it is just an interface. That is why I want to extend an already implemented type not an interface. I mentioned this in the question.

Comment: Why do you need to extend a class at all?  If you just want a fixed list, `listOf()` is probably the simplest option.  If you need to add/override your own functionality, you can extend an existing implementation such as `ArrayList`, or whatever else seems appropriate.  Or you can delegate to any `List`.